# CLI Application with docker

Tags: python, docker

I building a CLI python application that takes a CSV file as argument input and various options

Example:
 `rexona [-h] [-v | -q] [-o] filepath`

My question is how to dockerize it in a way that when I run my docker file I can run the above command and pass in the specified arguments?

My current docker file

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR .

COPY . .

CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

Should I also install an os image such as ubuntu, so that I can run cmd commands or is there a way to that in docker?

Apologies, I'm still new to docker.
Thanks

Comment: I'd run this in a host Python virtual environment in most cases.  The required `docker` command-line options to make this work will probably be longer than the actual command line to start your program, the container form will require root-equivalent privileges to run, and you'll need to install Docker to run it (where most Linux/MacOS systems have Python already).

Answer (score 4):

You need to add entry point for eg:

```
# Base image of the docker container
FROM python:3


# Copy the contents of the repo into the /app folder inside the container
COPY . /app
# Update the current working directory to the /app folder
WORKDIR /app

# Add your CLI's installation setups here using the RUN command
# If you have any pip requirements you can do that here
# RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

# Provdide a path to your cli apps executable
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "script.py" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I also run into similar senario i solved it using Entry point

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "script.py" ]
```

run script

```
docker run arg1 arg2 arg3...
```

And then in Python Program

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```